Aiogram кик пользователя по нейму
Здраствуйте, я хочу научить бота выполнять команду кика, как это сделать? Могу написать примерную команду
kick @ТегЮзера
мне нужно именно по тегу юзера, не ответным сообщением...
@router.message(Command("kick")) 
async def kick(message: Message):
    await message.bot.ban_chat_member(message.chat.id, message.reply_to_message.from_user.id)

Что в этом коде нужно изменить чтобы кикать не ответным сообщением, а по @юзернейму

А если у пользователя нет юзернейма?

в ban_chat_member вторым аргументом вы должны передать id пользователя. Вероятно вам необходимо создавать БД, в которую будете заносить id и username пользователей, которые добавляются в вашу группу. Далее, при необходимости банить именно по username вам нужно получать id из БД и подставлять вторым аргументом в ban_chat_member. Просто получить id по username скорее всего нельзя
